# Search list items in another longer list in python

Tags: python, regex, list, lookup

I am new to this forum, hence apologies if this is a very long question.

I am trying create a generic keyword parser that accepts a keyword list and a list of text lines (that could have been either generated from a DB or a free format text file). Now I am trying to extract the entities from the Text lines list based on the keyword list so that I can generate three key outputs;

1. Keyword that was mentioned
2. The text line where this keyword was mentioned and,
3. the number of times this keyword was mentioned in the text line

The following is a sample of the python code I have written to do this. As you can see that I am trying to accomplish this in three stages;

Stage 1 - accept a reject sequence so that I can remove all known unwanted lines from the Text lines list

Stage 2 (Pass 1 parsing) - Carry out a index-type search on the keywords to reduce the list of lines I need to do a full looped search

Stage 3 - Carry out a full looped search.

Problem: The problem I have is that the stage 3 (or pass 2 in the code) is extremely in-efficient and as an example for the keyword list that has 4500 elements and for the text lines with nearly 2 million rows the code runs for more than 24 hours.

Can anyone suggest a better method of doing the pass 2? 
or 
If there is a better method of writing the whole function?

I am a Python beginner hence if I have missed something obvious, then apologies  in advance.

```
##########################################################################################
# The keyWord parser conducts a 2 pass keyword lookup and parsing.
# Inputs:
#  keywordIDsList - Is a list of the IDs of the keyword (Standard declaration: keywordIDsList[]= Hash value of the keyWords)
#  KeywordDict - is the Dict of all the keywords and the associated ID.
#          (Standard declaration: keywordDict[keywordID]=(keywordID, keyWord) where keywordID is hash value in keywordIDsList)
#  valueIDsList - Is a list of the IDs of all the values that need to be parsed (Standard declaration: valueIDsList[]= Unique reference number of the values)
#  valuesDict - Is the Dict of all the value lines and the associated IDs.
#          (Standard declaration: valuesDict[uniqueValueKey]=(uniqueValueKey, valueText) where uniqueValueKey is the unique key in valueIDsList)
#  rejectPattern - A regular expression based pattern for rejecting columns with certain types of patterns. This is an optional field.
# Outputs:
#  parsedHashIDsList - Is the a hash value that is generated for every successful parse results
#  parsedResultsDict - Is actual parsed value as parsedResultsDict[parsedHashID]=(uniqueValueKey, keywordID, frequencyResult)
#  successResultIDsList - list of all unique value references that were parsed successfully
#  rejectResultIDsList - list of all unique value references that were rejected
##########################################################################################

def keywordParser(keywordIDsList, keywordDict, valueIDsList, valuesDict, rejectPattern):
    parsedResultsDict = {}
    parsedHashIDsList = []
    successResultIDsList = []
    rejectResultIDsList = []
    processListPass1 = []
    processListPass2 = []
    idxkeyWordDict = {}

    for keyID in keywordIDsList:
        keywordID, keyWord = keywordDict[keyID]
        idxkeyWordDict[keyWord] = (keywordID, keyWord)

    percCount = 1
    #    optional: if rejectPattern is provided then reject lines
    # ## Some python code for processing the reject patterns - this works fine

    #    Pass 1: Index based matching - partial code for index based search
    for valueID in processListPass1:
        valKey, valText = valuesDict[valueID]
        try:
            keyWordVal, keywordID = idxkeyWordDict[valText]
        except:
            processListPass2.append(valueID)

    percCount = 0

    #   Pass 2: Text based search and lookup - this part of the code is extremely inefficient

    for valueID in processListPass2:
        percCount += 1
        valKey, valText = valuesDict[valueID]
        valSuccess = 'N'
        for keyID in keywordIDsList:
            keyWordVal, keywordID = keywordDict[keyID]
            keySearch = re.findall(keyWordVal, valText, re.DOTALL)
            if keySearch:
                parsedHashID = hash(str(valueID) + str(keyID))
                parsedResultsDict[parsedHashID] = (valueID, keywordID, len(keySearch))
                valSuccess = 'Y'
        if valSuccess == 'Y':
            successResultIDsList.append(valueID)
        else:
            rejectResultIDsList.append(valueID)

    return (parsedResultsDict, parsedHashIDsList, successResultIDsList, rejectResultIDsList)
```

Comment: This seems like a good question but you're likely to get better answers if you cut down the example a bit - eg we don't need all the `print()` statements and can work out most of the variable usages from their names. Failing that, perhaps just show the problem (pass 2) in which case some detail on the initial variable state would be beneficial.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance I have removed all parts of the unwanted code though I have left code comments to help understand the use of the variables in the code.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but if you break it up into 3 functions, one for each pass, you'll be able to profile it much better.  If performance is a problem, you should run it with a small sample of data through [a profiler](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/profile.html) to identify exactly where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I have timed the execution blocks. The reject records and the pass 1 code works fine and completes in sub-seconds. The pass 2 code is the where the problem lies, the loop through all the keywords in the keyword list to look for their occurrence in the text lines list takes a very long time for processing 100 records the pass 2 part of the code take 2 minutes. Since i am beginner, I am trying to find out if there is a better method of dealing with the pass 2 part of the code.

Comment: You may want to extract a smaller sample code with a few lines of sample data for the key problem, so that people can play with it and give you suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for the [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). There is an explanation of a similar use case using code examples in python in [this blog post](http://papercruncher.com/2012/02/26/string-searching-using-aho-corasick/).

Comment: Looks promising... I will revert back once I have understood how to adapt this to my use-case.
cheers...